# access a json field value if the json field has special chars as dots

Tags: karate

If I have a json file with fields having special chars (in my case dots) how can I access the field value in Karate?

For example having a json file called example.json

```
{
  "field1" : {
      "field2" : "value2",
      "field.3" : "value3"
  }
}
```

if I want to get the value of "field.3" field how can do?

```
  Scenario: read a json file
    * def myJson = read("example.json")
    * match myJson.field1.field2 == "value2"
    * match myJson.field1.field.3 == "value3" # this fails
    * match myJson.field1."field.3" == "value3" # this fails
    * match myJson.field1.'field.3' == "value3" # this fails
    * match myJson.field1.'field\.3' == "value3" # this fails
```

Comment: Have you tried square bracket notation? That often works `myJson.field1['field.3']`

Comment: Yes thanks, with this it works: 

`* match myJson.field1['field.3'] == "value3"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use square-brackets:

```
* myJson.field1['field.3']
```